# Bottom of Background Color/Background-Image is Cut Off On Mobile Site

Tags: css, html, mobile, responsive-design, background-image

I've gone through the answers for similar questions and none of the answers helped with this issue. My background image is being cut off on the bottom at the viewport. If I remove the background image and put a solid color as the background the same thing happens. The text on the mobile page can be seen, the background just cuts off.

View the site using Chrome's device mode as iPhone 6 to replicate. Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated!

[Dev site](http://rosasfreelancedesign.com/dev/douglas/mobile/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `content` element is set to `height:100%` which makes it 100% of its *parent's* height. It ends up not being tall enough to fit the 1000px tall element within it. Normally the element would just expand to contain its contents, but your `height` attribute overrides that behavior.

`content` also doesn't seem like it needs to be `position:absolute;` either. That isn't helping the sizing issue.

I would get rid of:

```
div.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then also remove the inline-style `height: 1000px` on the `.page` element.

Comment: That's what I get for hodgepodging various CSS techniques together, thanks for the help!